# How to ignore timezone in csv data

Tags: csv, gnuplot, timezone-offset

I have some csv data I'm trying to plot in gnuplot.

example:

```
1,2014-11-07T16:00:03+13:00
2,2014-11-07T15:55:03+13:00
3,2014-11-07T15:50:04+13:00
4,2014-11-07T15:45:03+13:00
5,2014-11-07T15:40:03+13:00
6,2014-11-07T15:35:03+13:00
```

This won't work

```
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
```

These are New Zealand dates which will change between +12:00 and +13:00

I realise that gnuplot doesn't play nice with timezones.  I don't have the option to remove the zone at the source, so how do I set it to just ignore the +13:00 so it's just working in my local time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gnuplot's string functions to remove the time zone part from the data. In this case you don't need to use `set timefmt`, but the time values are parsed inside the `using` statement with `strptime`.

```
set datafile separator ','
set xdata time

fmt = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
timeval(s) = strptime(fmt, substr(s, 0, strstrt(s, '+')-1))

plot 'data.csv' using 1:(timeval(strcol(2)))
```